# Insert substring right before first occurrence of another string

Tags: php, string, variables, substring, limit

Take for example these strings:

```
  $strOne = "Place new content here:  , but not past the commma.";
  $strTwo = "test content";
```

So based on the strings above, how do make a new string that looks like this:

```
  $finalstr = "Place new content here:  test content, but not past the comma.";
```

*EDIT*

Also, lets assume I don't have access to $strOne, meaning I want to modify it via string functions not directly the string via concatenation etc...

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: not sure what functions php has to do this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a combination of `strpos` and `substr_replace` ?

```
$strOne = "Place new content here:  , but not past the commma.";
$strTwo = "test content";

// find the position of comma first
$pos = strpos($strOne, ',');
if ($pos !== false)
{
     // insert the new string at the position of the comma
     $newstr = substr_replace($strOne, $strTwo, $pos, 0);
     var_dump($newstr);
}
```

Output:

> string(63) "Place new content here: test content, but not past the
>   commma."

Answer (score 4):

You can split the first string by comma and then concat in the way you want. To split you may use [explode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) method:

```
$strArray = explode(',', $strOne, 2);
$finalstr = $strArray[0].$strTwo.",".$strArray[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace()` does not have the capability to limit the number of replacements.  `preg_replace()` though not necesary for finding your needle in the haystack string DOES allow replacement limiting.  Using `explode()` is not a horrible approach, but you should limit the explosions to `2` if you use it.  I do not like the indirect-ness of generating a temporary array when a string result is sought.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/LHOTK))

```
$strOne = "Place new content here:  , but not past the commma.";
$strTwo = "test content";

echo preg_replace('/,/', "$strTwo,", $strOne, 1);
```

You could use `preg_replace('/(?=,)/', $strTwo, $strOne, 1)` to avoid mentioning the needle in the replacement string, but that regex will perform worse because the lookahead will be performed on every step while traversing the haystring string -- not great.

If your needle string might contain characters that have special meaning to the regex engine, then use `'/' . preg_quote($yourNeedle, '/') . '/'` as your pattern.

---

If your needle is more variable, then use the same regex technique.  If wanting to find the first hashtag substring in a block of text, merely search for the first occurring `#` followed by one (or more) word character(s).  If you want to enforce that the `#` is preceded by a space, you can add that too.  You can use a lookahead to avoid copying the needle into the replacement parameter but this might execute a little slower depending on the quality of the haystack string.

Input:

```
$strOne = "Programming requires life long learning #learning #stackoverflow #programming";
$strTwo = "\n\n";
```

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/tYgPb))

```
echo preg_replace('/#\w/', "$strTwo$0", $strOne, 1);
// or echo preg_replace('/ (#\w)/', "$strTwo$1", $strOne, 1); // to replace the preceding space with 2 newlines
```

Or: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/MsYHh))

```
echo preg_replace('/ \K(?=#\w)/', $strTwo, $strOne, 1);
```

Answer (score -2):

With your first example:

```
$strTwo = "test content";
$strOne = "Place new content here: $strTwo, but not past the commma.";
```

To go further: use an array of string, and create a function which returns the concatenations of the strings.

Answer (score -2):

```
$finalstr = str_replace(',', $strTwo.',', $strOne, 1);
```