# Add newlines to separate text and only hashtags that appear at the end of the string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, limit, hashtag

I've already tried a couple of regex but cannot fix this one:

I need an enter line before the hashtags start (so there is some space).

Example:

> It's essential to keep your pup cool in the summer months! Try to keep
> them out of the heat as much as possible - keep the house cool,
> provide shade and run a fan for them if you can. #Dogs #Animals
> #Summer #DogCare #Humidity #HeatStroke #Cooling #HeatExhaustion #StayCool #HealthyPups

Should be:

> It's essential to keep your pup cool in the summer months! Try to keep
> them out of the heat as much as possible - keep the house cool,
> provide shade and run a fan for them if you can.
>
> #Dogs #Animals #Summer #DogCare #Humidity #HeatStroke #Cooling #HeatExhaustion #StayCool #HealthyPups

If there is a hashtag in the text it should not add whitespace, for example (note hashtags in text!):

> It's essential to keep your pup cool in the summer months! Try to keep
> them out of the heat as much as #possible - keep the house cool,
> #provide shade and run a #fan for them if #you can. #Dogs #Animals #Summer #DogCare #Humidity #HeatStroke #Cooling #HeatExhaustion #StayCool #HealthyPups

How can I solve this with Regex and PHP?

Comment: So if I said "I love pizza! #pizza #pepperoni #PizzaPizza Did I mention I love pizza?" - there should **not** be a break because there's additional non-hash stuff at the end?

Comment: What's the objective difference between the two cases? The hashtags are always "in the text".

Comment: Yes correct! Chris

Comment: Only the hashtag group at the end should have space inbetween.

Comment: So if the text ends with a series of hashtags, you want a newline before the first one?

Comment: Yes thats correct Barman

Comment: Related: [Insert substring right before first occurrence of another string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32530409/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match a series of hashtags with the regexp:

```
(?:#\w+\s*)+$
```

- `#\w+` matches a single hashtag
- `\s*` matches the optional whitespace between the hashtags
- `+` after the group matches a sequence of at least one of these
- `$` matches the end of the input string.

You can then use `preg_replace()` to insert a blank line before this.

```
$text = preg_replace('/((?:#\w+\s*)+)$/', "\n\n$1", $text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Match a space which is followed by one or more sequences of hashtags until the end of the string.  Inform `preg_replace()` to make only 1 replacement by adding `1` as the fourth parameter.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cUHKZ))

```
echo preg_replace('/ (?=(?:#[a-z]+\s*)+$)/i', "\n\n",  $text, 1);
```

Or without a lookahead or a replacement limit: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9lPUG))

```
echo preg_replace('/ ((?:#[a-z]+\s*)+)$/i', "\n\n$1",  $text);
```

Both approaches will cleanly replace the space before the sequence of hashtags with the two newlines.